# Camera takes dark image with iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapture

I am working on a media app and for capturing images. I am using AVcapture. Everything is working fine but I am facing an issue : when I am taking 5 images in a row using the camera, the first picture usually comes darker than the others.

My code for capture is as below:

```
   [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    [session beginConfiguration];
    // Create device input and add to current session
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create video output and add to current session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];
```

Does anyone know where does my issue come from?

Comment: Have you looked at the `adjustingExposure` property on your `AVCaptureDevice`?

Comment: @Mats-no ,I am new to this,can you help me more?

Comment: I have not used it in my code..